# How can I fix my code? Quick-sort fill with random numbers

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a code using quicksort but can't seen to make it work.

I have declared my array to size 20 and filled it with random integers. Then I called my `sort` method to do the quicksorting. The `show` method just prints the output. Still my code doesn't work at all.

My entire code for quick-sorting:

```
public class JavaApplication3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QuickSort B = new QuickSort();

        int[] snum = new int [20];
        for(int index = 0; index < snum.length; index++ ){
            snum[index]= (int) (Math.random ());
        } 

        B.sort(snum);
        B.show(snum);     
    }
}

class QuickSort{
    public static void sort(int [] a ){
        quicksort(a, 0, a.length -1);
    }

    private static void quicksort(int[] a, int lo, int hi){
        if(hi <= lo) return;
        int j = partition(a, lo, hi);
        quicksort(a, lo, j-1);
        quicksort(a, j+1, hi);
    }

    private static void exch(int [] a, int i, int j){
        int t = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = t;
    }

    private static int partition(int[] a, int lo, int hi){
        int i= lo;
        int j = hi+1;
        int pivot = a[lo]; 
        while(i<=j){
            while(a[i] < pivot){
                i++;
            }
            while(a[j] > pivot){
                j--;
            }
            if(i <= j){
                exch(a, i, j);
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        if (lo < j)
            quicksort(a, lo, j);
        if (i < hi)
            exch(a, i, j);

       return j;
    }

    public static void show(int[]a){
        for(int i=0; i<a.length;i++)
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   20    at javaapplication3.QuickSort.partition(JavaApplication3.java:61)
>     at javaapplication3.QuickSort.quicksort(JavaApplication3.java:43)   at
>   javaapplication3.QuickSort.sort(JavaApplication3.java:39)     at
>   javaapplication3.JavaApplication3.main(JavaApplication3.java:29) Java
>   Result: 1

Comment: what isn't working and why are you using static methods?

Comment: @Aツ  I am getting IndexOutofBound but I have declare the size of my array. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Please post the _actual error_ --- the traceback in its entirety.  It's whole job is to tell you what went wrong and where.

Comment: @Aツ  "why are you using static methods?"  ---  Alternatively, "why are you instantiating the `QuickSort` class?"  Either one could make sense, but doing both is weird.

Comment: I have been following a book example. It does work with Strings but I decided to make changes so it works with random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that Math.random produces fractional numbers less than one, and when you cast it to int, those numbers result in 0.  So multiply math.random by 10.

Comment: I did, somehow it's not there. Still, I encounter the same logic error.

Comment: Ill show you my implementation of Hoare's partition.

Comment: Can you add your Hoare's partition in your first answer. I can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
int hoaresPartition(int *arr, int lo, int hi){
    int pivot = arr[lo];
    int i = lo - 1;
    int j = hi + 1;
    while (true){

        do {
            j = j -1;
        }while (arr[j] > pivot);

        do {
            i = i+1;
        }while (arr[i] < pivot);

        if ( i < j){
            int temp;
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }else
            return j;
    }
}
```

Comment: A blob of code isn't much of an answer, even if it returns the correct results.  In this case it's less helpful than usual, because you've provided a whole new method without indicating what it should replace or how it should be used, let alone how it solves the problem.  A couple lines of text can make the (huge) difference between a useful answer and a puzzle.